# Убрать из строки лишнее и оставить только email'ы

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть строка с сотрудниками, пример:

> Сидоров Дмитрий Павлович Sidorov-dp@work.ru; Иванов Иван Иванович
> Ivanov-VI@work.ru; Петрова Луися Вазегновна {УВОЛЕН} Petrova-LV@work.ru;

Нужно очистить ее от лишнего и оставить только email'ы сотрудников без метки УВОЛЕН, результат должен быть такого вида:

> Sidorov-dp@work.ru; Ivanov-VI@work.ru;

Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить в дзене python, ибо мне на ум приходят только костыли аля:

```
str1 = 'Сидоров Дмитрий Павлович <Sidorov-dp@work.ru>; Иванов Иван Иванович <Ivanov-VI@work.ru>; Петрова Луися Вазегновна {УВОЛЕН} <Petrova-LV@work.ru>;'
find_emails = str1.split(';')
for item in find_emails:
    if 'УВОЛЕН' not in item:
        print(item)
```

но тут будет все остальное и кроме самих email'ов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у Вас действительно все, как в примере, то возможен такой вариант:

```
from itertools import chain
import re

str_of = 'Сидоров Дмитрий Павлович Sidorov-dp@work.ru; Иванов Иван Иванович Ivanov-VI@work.ru; Петрова Луися Вазегновна {УВОЛЕН} Petrova-LV@work.ru;'
print(list(chain.from_iterable([re.findall('([A-Za-z].*)', i) for i in str_of.split(';') if 'УВОЛЕН' not in i])))

>>>['Sidorov-dp@work.ru', 'Ivanov-VI@work.ru']
```

либо такой вариант (более универсальный):

```
print(list(chain.from_iterable([re.findall('[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', i) for i in str_of.split(';') if 'УВОЛЕН' not in i])))

>>> ['Sidorov-dp@work.ru', 'Ivanov-VI@work.ru']
```

Answer (score 1):

для приведенного примера работает еще такая регулярка:

```
from re import findall

str1 = 'Сидоров Дмитрий Павлович <Sidorov-dp@work.ru>; Иванов Иван Иванович <Ivanov-VI@work.ru>; Петрова Луися Вазегновна {УВОЛЕН} <Petrova-LV@work.ru>;'


findall(r'(?<!{УВОЛЕН} )<(.*?)>', str1)  # ['Sidorov-dp@work.ru', 'Ivanov-VI@work.ru']
```